# Popular segundo select após selecionar o primeiro select

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

boa noite!

Quero popular o segundo select com os dados dependendo do primeiro select, tenho o seguinte código

**View**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#relatorio").change(function(){
      $.ajax({
         type: "POST",
         url: "carregaDados",
         data: {relatorio: $("#relatorio").val()},
         dataType: "json",
         success: function(json){
            console.log(json);
            var options = "";
            $.each(json, function(key, value){
               options += '<option value="' + key + '">' + value + '</option>';
            });
            $("#filtro").html(options);
         }
      });
   });
});
```

---

```
<div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Relatório</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">                                                                                            
                                                <select class="form-control" name="relatorio" id="relatorio">
                                                    <option value="0">Escolha um relatório</option>
                                                    <option value="chamadosCliente">Chamados por cliente</option>
                                                    <option value="chamadosTecnico">Chamados por Tecnico</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>

                                       <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-3 control-label" for="filtro">Filtro</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-9">                                                                                            
                                                <select class="form-control" name="filtro" id="filtro">

                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
```

**Controller**

```
public function carregaDados(){

        $this->load->model('clientes_model');
        $clientes = $this->clientes_model->buscaNomeCliente();
        echo json_encode($clientes);
}
```

**Model**

```
public function buscaNomeCliente(){
        $this->db->select('id, razaoSocial');
        $query = $this->db->get('clientes');
        return $query->result();
    }
```

Mas quando ele retorna os dados pro ajax na View, retorna assim:

```
Array [ Object, Object ]
```

Não retorna os dados como tem que ser, alguém pode me ajudar?

Obrigado!

Comment: De um console.log(json) pelo chrome e veja qual a estrutura de dados está sendo retornada. Ao que parece ele está retornando um array de Json

Answer (score 0):

Percebi quem em seu controller você retorna os dados através da linha `json_encode($clientes);`

Isso faz com que você retorne um objeto com sua representação JSON.
Logo, na resposta de sucesso do seu AJAX, você precisa convertê-lo de volta para poder interpretar seu objeto.

Para que isso ocorra, você deve incluir a seguinte linha dentro do seu callback de success AJAX:

```
json = JSON.stringify(json);
```

Agora, seu objeto está convertido para o tipo String JSON.

Documentação:

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Não deu certo!!

Comment: Algum erro no console? Como fica o objeto no debug? Se não te for útil, tente fazer através dessa linha: json = JSON.parse(json); E nos informe por favor se funcionou.